# How to find the "sum" of two parametric curves?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, curves, computational-geometry

Given two parametric 2D curves:

$c_1=[x_1(a),y_1(a)], \text{ for } a\in[0,1]$

$c_2=[x_2(b),y_2(b)], \text{ for } b\in[0,1]$

I want to find the "sum" of these curves, which I define as the points $[x,y]$ for which there exists $a,b$ such that

1. $x=x_1(a)+x_2(b)$
2. $y = y_1(a) = y_2(b)$.

I suspect the result should also be a curve, since there is only one degree of freedom given the constraint $2$). I approached this by brute-forcing it, checking all points $[a,b]$ in a grid and keeping those that satisfy constraint $2$) (with a given margin), and indeed the result $[x,y]$ looks like a curve (see example below, where the right curve shows the "sum" of the two curves on the left).

[image: The brute force solution example]

However, extending this to more input curves becomes computationally expensive, since each new curve would add a new dimension to the grid. Notice that it is impossible to add curves sequentially in this way, since the result is a list of sparse points, instead of a parametric curve.

This question has a physical origin: if two physical systems with a non-linear relationship between parameters (e.g., pressure and temperature) are connected in such a way that one of the parameters must be the same in both, what would be the resulting curve for the total system?

Would you know of any more efficient way to get the resulting curve? Or any other way this could be extended to more input curves in an efficient way?

Comment: In your second criterion, you write y(a) and y(b). What's y()?

Comment: Same thing here - the "since there is only one degree of freedom given the constraint 2)" bit is a bit confusing, too.

Comment: @JonathanZ I'm guessing they meant $y = y_1(a) + y_2(b)$

Comment: not exactly, I meant y=y1(a)=y2(b), wich means that the results whould be those that satisfy this equality condition

Comment: You should include your brute force grid Diagram here. that will clarify your thinking to the users , to get Better Answers.. What Curves you used , What Curve you got , What Curve you wanted to get , ETC.

Comment: That in general won't define a curve. What happens if the two original curves doesn't intersect? Then it won't exists $a$ and $b$ such that $y_1(a)=y_2(b)$. What happens if for a given $a$ there exists many values of $b$ such that $y_1(a)=y_2(b)$? Then the pair $(a,b)$ is not uniquely defined and the value of $x_1(a)+x_2(b)$ can't be determined.

Comment: I am actually mostly interested in the second case, please see the example I just added, even when multiple solutions exist for each $y$, the result still looks like a curve

Comment: I advise you to reconsider your issue by taking instead : $x=\tfrac12(x_1(a)+x_2(b)), y=\tfrac12(y_1(a)+y_2(b))$ : indeed working with midpoints is more intuitive.

Comment: If $a_0$ and $b_0$ are such that $(x1(a_0), y1(a_0)$ is not a crossing-point of curve c1, and $(x2(b_0), y2(b_0))$ is not a crossing-point of curve c2, then the curves are locally inversible around $a_0$ and $b_0$, so you should be able to rewrite the sum-curve locally.

Comment: Although note that if $y1$ or $y2$ is constant on an interval, then the sum-curve will not be a curve but will have a portion of a surface.